# Sql Query to join table and coalesce values

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm a newbie to sql and am trying to to join two tables and coalesce values.
the Coalesce code below works when run individually

```
Select  @ContactName = COALESCE(@ContactName + ', ', '') + c.ContactName from contacts  c inner join  functions b on c.pid= b.pid
```

but when i combine the whole code its not executing. Could someone advise be on the below.

```
 select 
a.*,
b.tfunction, 
b.SSummary,
b.ContactType,
(  Select  @ContactName = COALESCE(@ContactName + ', ', '') + c.ContactName from contacts  c inner join  functions b on c.pid = b.pid),
(   Select  @Address = COALESCE(@Address + ', ', '') + c.Address from contacts  c inner join  functions b on c.pid = b.pid),
(  Select  @ContactPhone = COALESCE(@ContactPhone + ', ', '') + c.ContactPhone from contacts  c inner join  functions b on c.pid = b.pid),
(    Select  @ContactEmail = COALESCE(@ContactEmail + ', ', '') + c.ContactEmail from contacts  c inner join  functions b on c.pid = b.pid)
from contracts a
inner join functions b on a.pid = b.pid
```

ERROR details

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

ps:- feel free to modify the code.

PS- i have the declare variable for all the 4 attributes - Stack overflow is not allowing me to paste them for some reason.

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you receiving an error?  Is it not returning what you expect?  Please be more descriptive.  `its not executing` is not very much information about your problem.

Comment: error details Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: basically the query is not executing.

Comment: d.ContactType is invalid.  You have only declared tables with "a" and "b"

Comment: typo - made the update its b.contacttype

Comment: You cannot combine variable assignment statements and a return result set in the same SQL.

Comment: How do you suggest i proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
 select a.*, b.tfunction, b.SSummary, b.ContactType,
        (Select  @ContactName = COALESCE(@ContactName + ', ', '') + c.ContactName
         from contacts  c inner join 
              functions b
              on c.pid = b.pid
        ),
        (Select  @Address = COALESCE(@Address + ', ', '') + c.Address
         from contacts  c inner join
              functions b
              on c.pid = b.pid
        ),
        (Select @ContactPhone = COALESCE(@ContactPhone + ', ', '') + c.ContactPhone
         from contacts  c inner join 
              functions b
              on c.pid = b.pid
        ),
        (  varchar(1000)  Select  @ContactEmail = COALESCE(@ContactEmail + ', ', '') + c.ContactEmail
         from contacts  c inner join
              functions b
              on c.pid = b.pid
         )
from contracts a inner join
     functions b
     on a.pid = b.pid;
```

This has multiple obvious *syntax* errors:

- You cannot set a variable value inside a subquery.  In fact, a query cannot both return rows and set variable values.
- the `varchar(1000)` is just hanging out there, as if you were trying to do a cast in C or something.

Then you have additional logic errors:

- Assigning and using a variable in the same statement.
- Subqueries that return more than one row.
- Lack of correlation in what look to be correlated subqueries.

You appear to want to get lists of things from the contacts.  This is a pain in SQL Server, but perhaps this will put you on the right path:

```
 select a.*, b.tfunction, b.SSummary, b.ContactType,
        stuff((select ', ', c.ContactName
               from contacts c
               where c.pid = b.pid
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, '') as Contacts,
        stuff((Select ', ' + c.Address
                from contacts c
                where c.pid = b.pid
                for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, '') as Addresses,
         . . .
from contracts a join
     functions b
     on a.pid = b.pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that with your INNER JOIN, there must be a row in FUNCTIONS to see any results.

If you want the row in CONTACTS to show even if a row in FUNCTIONS does not match, then replace the INNER JOIN with a LEFT JOIN.

```
Select  
    @ContactName = COALESCE(@ContactName + ', ', '') + c.ContactName 
from contacts  c 
LEFT join  functions b on c.pid= b.pid
```

Comment: even if i replace with left join same issue. The query is not executing. giving the below error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Have you declared @ContactName?  e.g. DECLARE @ContactName varchar(max); set @ContactName=''

Comment: i did, stack over flow would not let me add that snippet.

Comment: yes re-checked and checked again and copied/pasted the declared attributes.